# Getting joined entity and count not working

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I 'm trying to execute this query but I get an error:

```
select c, count(i) as total 
from \Invoice i 
join i.client c 
GROUP BY i.client
```

Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.

What is wrong? I want to get all the client entity fields

Comment: I don't really understand your query, `join i.client c`? Is this MSSQL?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
select c.*, count(c.id) as total 
from \Invoice i 
join i.client c 
GROUP BY c.id
```

I do not really know if this works but in Doctrine1's DQL implementation this would be the right way to go.